# Routing 101 help with two CradlePoint Routers

Tags: routing, router

**edited to be more specific*

I have two mobile trailers and two retail stores.  The trailers travel around the country as a mobile retail store.  Each location is running a IP scheme as 192.168.1.xxx, 192.168.2.xxx, 192.168.3.xxx, 192.168.4.xxx respectively.  99% of the traffic is internal since all the web and database servers, POS systems, etc are on board.  Using a CradlePoint MBR1400 wireless router access the internet via mobile broadband.  But the internet is mainly for just checking email, and music.  No VPN or anything else is used.

Every once in a while, to expand the number of POS systems and the number of customers we can process, two trailers or a trailer and a retail store need to work together.

Being that each location can operate independently they run their own databases.  So when we bring them together we only run one database server, one web server.  on the "master" trailer (say the one running 192.168.1.xxx).

Since the POS system is all web based, the slave trailer would simply point to the master web server 192.168.1.3.

So I simply need to know how to setup routes, so on the slave (192.168.2.x) I can type in 192.168.1.3 and reach the master web server.

I know CradlePoint allows RIP, OSPF, BGP, and static routes.  Is there any way I can get these two networks talking to each other?

Thanks

Comment: How are you connecting your two locations?

Comment: Good question.  The sites are mobile trailers.  So they will be connected via ethernet.

Comment: Matt it is unclear how we can help.  If this is a question about how to configure routing we need more details,  such as a copy of the network map including ip addresses and device names.  Please be explicit about how exactly we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'll bite. I guess you have a router for each trailer right, serving as the main router for the network. Configure a port on each with a interface with an IP in what we'll call the "backbone" network. For example 192.168.0.0/24

Now, for a small network like this, you don't need anything fancy when it comes to routing protocols, but to make the whole shebang "automagically" work, I'd suggest using one. Your routers need to support it, and you want it to be nice and easy, so I'd go with RIP or something.

Next, hook up the interfaces you configured with a switch, and the routers should all advertise their internal networks to the other routers. If you set it up right so that the default route on each trailer router points to the WAN interface, internet connectivity shouldn't be interfered with.

If you don't have a router in each trailer, then you can just configure 4 interfaces on a router with matching settings for each network, and do away with the routing protocols. The machines in the network would need their default gateway pointing at the routers IP address of course. Here you would also need to attach any WAN gear to the router and set it's default route to point to that interface, but it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have only two internal networks connected over Ethernet, the easiest way is to configure one static route on every router for the remote internal LAN.
On router 1: 192.168.2.0/24 with next-hop (gateway) IP address of second router
On router 2: 192.168.1.0/24 with next-hop (gateway) IP address of first router

Comment: without details is hard to answer this question. Next time try to write a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Matt, you need to internetwork your different private networks/locations together with a VPN.  Once you have a VPN nailed up, you will be able to www/http into 192.168.1.3 from any of the locations.  Specifically, you will be configuring a site-to-site VPN.  Looks like you may need the Enterprise License according to the [CradlePoint page](https://cradlepoint.com/products/arc-mbr1400).

Comment: A VPN would work but OP is asking about local routing between two routers.

Comment: @IsAGuest, "internet via mobile broadband", the PE router is not going to peer with the customer routers with an IGP, will not route RFC1918 private network ranges.  He has to do a VPN or tunnel.  Right?